# How to remove extra escaping quote characters of JsonObject created through Javax

Tags: java, json, double-quotes

I use javax to create `JsonObject` and `JsonArray` from my `List<String>` and I have a list of Json objects that i want to put in a `JsonObject` through a `JsonArray`

```
    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder(); 
    for (String Obj : listOfJsonDfObjects) 
       jsonArray.add(summaryObj);   //{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}
   
    // this line introduces extra escaping quotes like this {"\"a\"":"\"b\""},{"\"c\"":"\"d\""}
    javax.json.JsonObject data = Json.createObjectBuilder()
       .add("data", jsonArray.build()).build();
```

How to avoid these extra quotes escaping characters?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre], probably even as a failing unit test, so your expectation is in the code.

Comment: Add the code where you populate your `List<String>`

Comment: it is out of scope of this question, but i show an example of such List: `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},..]`

Comment: If you are constrained to using the `javax.json` API and implementation, then you can take each string such as `{"a":"b"}` and extract its key and value (`a` and `b`) using plain Java. Then you can use `JsonObjectBuilder jsonObj = Json.createObjectBuilder()` and build a JSON object from each key and value - `jsonObj.add(key, val). Then add _that_ to your JSON array instead of adding the raw string.

Comment: Or, (if you are not constrained to `javax`) just use a library which can parse JSON-as-a-string directly to JSON objects and arrays (Jackson, Gson, etc.).

Comment: using Gson, i noticed the extra quotes as well. Could you show us the GSon example?

Comment: You need to store a JsonValue, not an actual String. get a JsonProvider.provider() and reuse that to createValue(String) when creating the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have a list of JSON objects, but you really have a list of JSON-formatted strings. To add them to a `JsonArray`, you need to parse each one into the JSON object model:

```java
public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfJsonDfObjects = List.of(
                "{\"a\":\"b\"}",
                "{\"c\":\"d\"}"
        );
        JsonArrayBuilder jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for (String summaryObj : listOfJsonDfObjects) {
            JsonReader parser = Json.createReader(new StringReader(summaryObj));
            jsonArray.add(parser.readObject());
        }

        JsonObject data = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("data", jsonArray.build()).build();

        System.out.println(data); // {"data":[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]}
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Gson

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(listOfJsonDfObjects);        
    //check json
    System.out.println(json);        
    json = json.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
    json = json.replaceAll("\"\\{", "{");
    json = json.replaceAll("\\}\"", "}");        
    //valid json now
    System.out.println(json);
```

A more secure way (to avoid altering original data)

```
    //concatenate objects in list with comma
    String json = String.join(",", listOfJsonDfObjects);
    //convert to pseudo array
    json = "[" + json + "]"; 
    //convert pseudo json array to pseudo json object
    json = "{\"data\":" + json + "}";
    //cast to json object
    JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);                       
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Comment: isn't it dangerous to replace characters as you do? you could inadvertently alter the main json data.

Comment: Yes, it is. I don’t think this will handle doubly-escaped quotes or braces correctly, if these appear inside string values in the original data.

Comment: You're right, I'll try to improve this code later.

Comment: Gson isn't necessary to do this properly